# What Part of speech is "back" in my sentences

Tags: phrases

Back in time.    Back in those days

What part of speech is "Back"  in those sentences

Comment: Why do you need to know? And what good will it do you if we gave you a definitive answer?

Answer (score 4):

The examples you give are not sentences because they lack a subject and a finite verb.  If you use your constructions in true sentences, they answer becomes clearer.  "I used a slide-rule back in time."  *Back* clearly modifies the verb and is used as an adverb.  A common colloquial use in American, and especially African-American English is *back in the day*, where *back* is an adverb and *in the day* is almost a grace note or a truncation of "back in the days of segregation."

Comment: Those two examples are phrases , my question is what type of phrases, noun phrase, adverbial phrase or prepositional phrase?